# How can i connect an Azure AD b2c User flow to an OAuthPrompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, botframework, azure-ad-b2c

so i set up my azure AD b2c User flow for sign in and login , but now i am confused on how to connect it to my OAuthPrompt and put the ConnexionName of it , and i want also for my bot to wait for the response and retreive the token given by the completed login and continue the rest of the Bot . and i can't find any documentation or examples with real values .
Ps : the code is in Node.js .

````
        .addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.promptStep.bind(this),
            this.initialStep.bind(this),
            this.finalStep.bind(this)
        ]))
        .addDialog(new OAuthPrompt(OAUTH_PROMPT, {
            connectionName: process.env.connectionName,
            text: 'Please Sign In',
            timeout: 300000,
            title: 'Sign In'
        }));```
````

Answer (score 0):

Just put the connectionName Value in your .env file and it should work fine.

Comment: What i wanted to ask is what are the possible values of the field ConnexionName